# How to change the task limit of supervisor on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

When I run the command: `systemctl status supervisor.service`
I see that the no of tasks is pretty close to the Limit, how can I increase the limit? I saw a few SO answers on this. But, none of them materize the change for me.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04